# Git push fails to push to origin - no such ref

Tags: git, git-flow, hotfix

I'm having trouble pushing commits on a `hotfix` branch created with `git-flow` to the remote repository.

Here is the error:

```
$ git push origin hotfix/MyHotfix
Counting objects:
... etc
To {my remote repo}
 ! [remote rejected] hotfix/MyHotfix -> hotfix/MyHotfix (no such ref)
error: failed to push some refs to {my remote repo}
```

I created the `hotfix` with the standard syntax:

```
git flow hotfix start MyHotfix
```

and this branch is already present on the `origin`, which I can see with `git branch -a`.
I have also checked that the branch is still present on the remote server, since it shows up when I run `git remote show origin`.

Has anyone come across this before with `git` or `git-flow` and found a solution?

Note - things I have tried:

- Re-cloning the remote repo -> same error
- Deleting the local branch -> same error
- Deleting the remote branch -> I can push the 'new' branch, but get the same error on my colleagues local repo when he tries to push a commit (after `git remote prune origin`)
- Force push -> same error
- Upstream push -> same error
- Checking refs -> my commit parent id matches the server

Update:

`git ls-remote origin` and `git show-ref` show different refs for the local and remote hotfix branches, but this is because I have 1 extra commit locally, and the parent commit's ref matches the ref on `origin`.

Comment: Did you try `git flow hotfix finish MyHotfix`?

Comment: That would close the hotfix, but still not fix the issue of being able to push a completely valid branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it was actually a problem with the server repository.
Running these steps on the bare repo on the server cleared up the error:

```
git fsck --full
git prune
git gc
```

Note: according to the man pages `git prune` isn't required because `git gc` calls it, but I was trying everything.

Comment: Excellent feedback, more accurate than my initial answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Considering [issue 92](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/92), I don't think hotfix branches are meant to be published.
This is a feature request which is still pending.

> While `release` and `feature` branches can all be published (`git flow release/feature publish`), hotfix branches cannot.

So maybe the push itself has been prevented to be compliant with the (already denied) publish operation.

Comment: I have previously been able to push the hotfix branch (since it is visible on origin) and I also tested `git flow hotfix publish Test`, which worked. I think issue 92 should actually be closed (and there is an associated pull request which is closed)

Comment: @Laurence then this branch must have been deleted on `origin`: what `git push -u origin hotfix/MyHotfix:hotfix/MyHotfix` returns?

Comment: That command gives the same error. I'm wondering if there is a mismatch between the branch name<->ref mapping on `origin` and on my machine. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: @Laurence `git fetch` followed by a `git branch -a` would give you the name of the remote branches (as well as the local ones).

Comment: Thanks @VonC, but I know the branch is present on the remote, it shows up with `git fetch && git branch -a` and also with `git remote show origin`